# Drag and drop in an NSView

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, nsdragginginfo

I'm testing drag and drop in an NSView, but `draggingEntered:` is never called.

Code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface testViewDrag : NSView <NSDraggingDestination>
@end

@implementation testViewDrag
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self)
{
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSImage imagePasteboardTypes]];
    NSLog(@"initWithFrame");
}
return self;
}

-(NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
NSLog(@"draggingEntered");
return NSDragOperationEvery;
}

-(NSDragOperation) draggingUpdated:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
  NSLog(@"draggingUpdated");
  return NSDragOperationEvery;
}
@end
```

In interface builder I add a `subView` (class is set to `testViewDrag`) to the main window. In log I can see the `initWithFrame` log but when I drag nothing is shown in the log.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"To receive drag operations, you must register the pasteboard types that your window or view will accept by sending the object a registerForDraggedTypes: message, defined in both NSWindow and NSView, and implement several methods from the NSDraggingDestination protocol. During a dragging session, a candidate destination receives NSDraggingDestination messages only if the destination is registered for a pasteboard type that matches the type of the pasteboard data being dragged. The destination receives these messages as an image enters, moves around inside, and then exits or is released within the destination’s boundaries." You can read more about the drag and drop programming topic [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragdestination.html). As I see it, your problem lies in the argument you define in your `registerForDraggedTypes:` method.

Try replacing it with this:

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        NSColorPboardType, NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you that work like a charm, if you can now tell me how to get paths of dragged files :)

Comment: For example,
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender {
NSArray * thefiles = [[sender draggingPasteboard] propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];

// Handle whatever you want here
}

Comment: i really appreciate your help, that was the las point in my application, thank you very much.